# Send image and additional informtion with AJAX to Servlet

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets

Bonjour,

I need to send an Image from a `<input type="file">` element to a servlet.
currently using ajax

```
var files;
$("input[type='file']").on("change",function(e) {
        files = e.target.files;
        $("#Submit-Button").prop({"disabled":false});
});

$("#Submit-Button").on("click", function(){

        var data = new FormData();
        $.each(files, function(key, value){
            data.append(key, value);
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: "UploadServlet",
            type : "POST",
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            dataType: JSON,
            processData : false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                //SUCCESS
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    //ERROR
            }
        });
    })
});
```

This is working and my servlet is receiving the file.

However i want to send some additional information to the servlet.

I tried (in the js ajax method)

```
data : {data: data, userID : userID, username: username},
```

and (in the java servlet)

```
String Filename = request.getParameter("uid") + request.getParameter("username")+".png";
Collection<Part> Parts = request.getParts();
```

which is obviously not working.

And now I can't think of anything that would solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The same way you add a file is the way you add any other data.

```
...
data.append('userID', userID);
data.append('username', username);
...
    $.ajax({
...
        data: data,
...
    });
```

[FormData.append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData#append())